# Redirect Admin user after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I want to redirect admin users to index action in the admin controller. but when I sign in as an admin and try to click on the admin page link,  I'm getting "status 404 " it's not accessible. 
I have the adminPartial view as the following:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   RidesDbContext context = new RidesDbContext();
   UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context);
   UserManager<IdentityUser, string> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser, string>(userStore);


   bool exist = userManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Admin");

   if (exist)
   {
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Admin Page", "Index", "Admin" , new { @class="nav-link"})
               </li>
        </ul>
   }
}
```

it's either navigate to the default index(homePage) or giving me an error status. 
index action in admin controller:

```
    // GET: Admin
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT: 
my index view is as the following:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPageDefault.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Styles/styleHomePage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/Animation.js"></script>
<div>
    <h2>RidesApp</h2>


    <div class="mask rgba-gradient d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="container">
            <!--Grid row-->
            <div class="row">
                <!--Grid column-->
                <div class="col-md-6 text-white text-center text-md-left mt-xl-5 mb-5 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                    <h1 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold mt-sm-5">Make purchases with our app </h1>
                    <hr class="hr-light">
                    <h6 class="mb-4">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem repellendus quasi fuga nesciunt
                        dolorum nulla magnam veniam sapiente, fugiat! Commodi sequi non animi ea dolor molestiae
                        iste.
                    </h6>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Sign up to Drive", "DriversRegistration", "Drivers")
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Sign up to Ride", "RidersRegistration", "Riders")

                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--Grid column-->
                <!--Grid column-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-5 mt-xl-5 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Transparent/Small/admin-new.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <!--Grid column-->
            </div>
            <!--Grid row-->
        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
<!--
```

it's using a shared layout page which has the rest of the navbar links.

Comment: What's the URL you're getting on the 404 page?

Comment: default/"Action name" (which is any action in the admin controller)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), there's no overload that match your parameters.

Try changing it to;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin Page", "Index", "Admin" , new { @class="nav-link"}, new { })
```

`[Authorize]` means any type of user as long as there logged in. If you are being redirected to the login page, that means you're not logged in at all. UNLESS your index view is the login page.

Comment: it's navigating me to the login page again even though the link is now existing in the navbar.

Comment: @hadeelKh If your index view is just a login form, then that's the expected behavior even though you're logged in.

Comment: @hadeelKh Will you include your index view?

Comment: Remove the `[Authorize]` attribute from the `Index` option and then try. If the page loads then you will know that there is a problem with the login. Otherwise check what hyperlink is generated in the browser for the nav bar Admin Page link.

Comment: I edit my question it's now including my index view.

Comment: @Rahatur I removed [Authorize] and now it's working . Thank you so much.